# Are Darboux Functions closed under uniform limit?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I suspect there exists a sequence of functions $f_n : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ s.t $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$, $f_n$ Darboux but $f$ not Darboux. However, I haven't found any examples. What are some examples?

Comment: This paper doesn't appear to answer your question directly, but it does study functions which are the uniform limit of Darbeaux functions: http://tcs.ieat.ro/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/marcus-hamel.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us denote $f$ the [Conway base 13 function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function), defined on $[0,1]$, which is a Darboux function and maps every interval onto $\mathbb{R}$.

Therefore $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is dense in $[0,1]$. Now we take $E = \{ a_k \mid k\in \mathbb{N} \}$ a countable subset of $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ which is dense in $[0,1]$.

*(to construct $E$, you can use that for all rational $q \in [0,1]$, there exists a sequence $(\alpha_{q,n}) \in \big(f^{-1}(\{0\})\big)^{\mathbb{N}}$ converging towards the rational $q$, and we can define $E$ as the union of all the $\alpha_{q,n}$. $E$ is obviously dense, and it is countable because $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$ is countable)*

$ $

The idea is now to construct $(f_n)$ such that $f_n^{-1}(\{0\})$ "shrinks".

With this $E$, you can define a sequence of function as follows : for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $f_n : [0,1] \longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and

$f_n\ \colon\ 
x\longmapsto\begin{cases}
2^{-k}&\text{if $x=a_k\ $ for $k\le n$}\\
0&\text{if $x=a_k\ $ for $k>n$}\\
1&\text{if $x \in f^{-1}(\{0\})\backslash E$} \\
f(x)&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

Using that $E$ is dense, $f_n$ still maps every interval onto $\mathbb{R}$.

Moreover, the sequence $(f_n)$ converges to some function $F$ and $||f_n-F||_{\infty} \leqslant \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$. Therefore $(f_n)$ is a sequence of Darboux functions which converges uniformly to $F$.

Yet, for all $a \in \mathbb{R}^*,\ F^{-1}(\{a\})$ is dense in $[0,1]$, but $F^{-1}(\{0\})$ is empty. Hence $F$ has both positive and negative images, but never vanishes, and therefore is not Darboux.

Comment: Great answer!! To summarize: Begin with  $f$ such that $f^{-1}(y)$ is dense for every $y \in \mathbb{R}$. Such a function is Darboux. We can ensure $E:=f^{-1}(0)$ is countable, say $E = \{a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots\}$. Define $f_n$ by changing the value of $f$ at $a_k$ from $0$ to $\frac{1}{k}$ for $1 \leq k \leq n$. Note $f_n$ is still Darboux, still taking every value on a dense set. However, the $f_n$ converge uniformly to a function $F$ which *never* takes the value $0$, but takes every other value on a dense set and such a function is *not* Darboux.

Comment: Thank you for summarizing it into something more readable